# php while из двух параллельных запросов?

Tags: php, mysql

Всем здравствуйте уважаемые программисты. Вот вопрос: 
Я на php делаю личные сообщения между пользователями но есть одно но. 
Все сообщения содержатся на одной таблице.
Там есть два поля user_from и user_to (от кого к кому).
Я делаю 2 запроса на таблицу чтобы отсортировать сообщения и показать от кого к кому. Эти 2 запроса я обрабатываю одним while. Типа:
while(($row_mess_2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_mess_2)) && ($row_mess_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_mess_1))).
Но этот запрос выводит четное количество данных. Например если в таблице 6 сообщений он выводит. А если вставить 7 запись он этого не выводит. Если вставить 8 запись то он показывает оба. В чем проблема можете подсказать? Место логического и(&&) подставлял логическое или(||) но не помогло.

Comment: вероятно у вас один цикл заканчивается раньше. покажите оба запроса, их надо объединять в один .... А то я не представляю как отдельные циклы чтения могут показать сообщения в правильном порядке, что если один пользователь пошлет два сообщения подряд ...

Answer (score 0):

В вашем случае не надо делать два запроса. Используйте только одни!
`INNER JOIN` или просто `JOIN` он соединит вам две таблицы!

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2  ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id
```